# POstgreSQL: как нужно залить дамп в терминал debian?

Tags: postgresql, debian, dump

Использую debian 9.5.0., который закачал себе на virtual box. Как я понимаю, дамп является текстовом файлом самой базы данных? (плохо разбираюсь) Подскажите, как нужно его залить в терминал, чтобы потом начать с ним работать.